# How do I know that a method in a DLL calls a method of another DLL?

Tags: c#, dependencies, call

For example:
There is API a.1 in DLL A and API B.1 in DLL B.
API A.1 calls API B.1.
Is there an open source tool or method to know this call path(A.1->B.1)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

.Net assemblies contain a list of referenced assemblies. This can be inspected by tools like [IL SPy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy).

There is no easy way to check if a specific method on one assembly may calls another assembly. You could perhaps inspect the CIL code for this, but it will require a bit more work.

There is also native dependencies, these are not listed in the same way, and use another method to load.